# Access 2010 SQL Query cannot add several form options

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am wanting to change this SQL query to reads several forms not just ![Prices]!

```
SELECT Option.Index, Option.Desc, Option.Price, Option.Price_ext, 
       Product.ID, OptionGroup.Option
FROM Product 
INNER JOIN (OptionGroup INNER JOIN [Option] ON OptionGroup.ID = Option.OptionGrp) 
  ON Product.ID = OptionGroup.Product
WHERE (((Product.ID)=[Forms]![Prices]![selName2]) AND ((OptionGroup.Option)="F"))
ORDER BY Option.Index;
```

Can any one help?

Comment: Assuming only for *Product.ID*, try `IN` clause: `(Product.ID) IN ([Forms]![Prices]![selName2], [Forms]![OtherForm1]![FieldName], [Forms]![OtherForm2]![FieldName], [Forms]![OtherForm3]![FieldName])`

Comment: Thank you for the fast response - I'm now getting a 'Syntax error (missing operator) for  (((Product.ID) IN ([Forms]![PriceBuilder]![selName2], [Forms]![EU]![selName2], [Forms]![US2]![selName2], [Forms]![Taiwan]![selName2]) And ((OptionGroup.Option)="A"))
ORDER BY Option.Index;

Comment: Be sure open/close parentheses match even around `IN()`.

Answer (score 0):

As commented, consider using the `IN()` operator with comma-separated items inside the `WHERE` clause which is equivalent to multiple `OR` statements. And be sure open/close parentheses match as shown below with exaggerated indentation:

```
SELECT o.[Index], o.Desc, o.Price, o.Price_ext, 
       p.ID, OptionGroup.Option
FROM Product p
INNER JOIN (OptionGroup INNER JOIN [Option] o ON OptionGroup.ID = o.OptionGrp) 
  ON p.ID = OptionGroup.Product
WHERE (
        (
          (p.ID) IN (
                     [Forms]![Prices]![selName2],
                     [Forms]![OtherForm1]![FieldName],
                     [Forms]![OtherForm2]![FieldName],
                     [Forms]![OtherForm3]![FieldName]
                    )
        )

        AND (
               (OptionGroup.[Option])='F'
            )
      )
ORDER BY o.[Index];
```